# Admob. Interstitial ads не отображается

Tags: xamarin, admob, ads, xamarin.android

Я использую Xamarin.Forms. У меня не отображается Interstitial реклама. ErrorCode возвращает 0. А IsLoaded (android) / IsReady(iOS) всегда возвращают false.

Говорят, что нужно подождать несколько часов и должна появится. Я прождал уже несколько дней.

Пермишены включены.

XAML:

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="40,0,40,0">  
    <Button Text="Interstitial" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="Blue"  BackgroundColor="White" Clicked="InterstitialAdShowClick"/>  
</StackLayout>
```

C#:

```
void InterstitialAdShowClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DependencyService.Get<IInterstitialAds>().ShowAd();
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IInterstitialAds
{
    void ShowAd();
}
```

Android:

```
public class AdInterstitial_Droid : Controls.Ad.IAdInterstitial
{
    InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    public AdInterstitial_Droid()
    {
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(Android.App.Application.Context)
        {
            AdUnitId = "ca-app-pub-xxx/xxx"
        };
        LoadAd();
    }

    void LoadAd()
    {
        var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        requestbuilder.AddTestDevice("xxx");
        interstitialAd.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());
    }

    public void ShowAd()
    {
        if (interstitialAd.IsLoaded) // тут всегда false
            interstitialAd.Show();

        LoadAd();
    }

    public override void OnAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode)
    {
        base.OnAdFailedToLoad(errorCode); // errorCode = 0
    }
}
```

В чём может быть проблема? Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Вы пробовали тестовые id?

Interstitial ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712

Interstitial Video  ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/8691691433

[id взяты отсюда](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads)

Может быть какие-то проблемы с Вашими id

Comment: С тестовыми работает реклама

Comment: @Viktor, попробуйте исправить / добавить платёжные настройки. После этого подождать 1-5 часов